# Can RedHat openjdk binaries for windows can be used in production without support contract?

Tags: java, redhat-openjdk

As I can see redhat is releasing the openjdk binaries for windows also https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/overview/ . However it says: 
"Download OpenJDK for Development Use" 
Does this mean it cant be used in production without support contract ?

Note: The reason I am asking is as we have been using RHEL 6 in our production boxes with openjdk binaries , so wants to keep the same binaries on windows boxes also as we are also deploying our services on Windows machines in production. Currently both have Oracle jdk but we are planning to migrate openjdk now.

Comment: We aren't RedHat, nor are we attorneys. Are your Windows boxes development machines or production machines? Because you mentioned you're using RHEL 6 in production.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes we are using Windows box on production and also have Unix boxes running with RHEL6. So For Unix system we are migrating to redhat provided openjdk binaries and to keep it consistent wants to use same jdk distribution on windows. As I found RedHat providing jdk binaries for windows also but wanted to ensure if its liable to be used in prod.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing, not about programming. Perhaps https://law.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: @Mureinik I understand its related to licensing but with new Java release/licensing  in Java subscription expects more programmers/experts aware of changes and help in understanding implications. As we have openjdk alternatives , and wants to understand how and which openjdk distribution from redhat can be used across platform from wider community experts.

Answer (score 1):

I think have got the required information and happy to found RedHat giving openjdk binaries under same license as AdoptOpenJDK which means it can be used in production.

Red Hat provides OpenJDK 8 Windows binaries under exactly the same license as AdoptOpenJDK and any other open-source OpenJDK 8 build - under the GNU GPL v. 2 with classpath exception.
Source : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/file/866ed739fa56/LICENSE
Got this from :
[Technical difference between AdoptOpenJDK and Red Hat OpenJDK for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202807/technical-difference-between-adoptopenjdk-and-red-hat-openjdk-for-windows)
Please correct me if I misunderstood from above.

Answer (score 0):

I have to correct myself, as got it clarified from RedHat that their openjdk distribution is not for production use without support contract or unless its part of RedHat Middleware product. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3116731